# How to create Clojure Zipper

Tags: clojure, zipper

How could I create the following graph using Clojure Zipper (`vector-zip`):

```
   A
 / | \      
B  C  D
     / \
    E   F
```

I have tried

```
(vector-zip ["A" ["B" "C" "D"["E" "F"]] ])
```

It returns

```
[["A" ["B" "C" "D" ["E" "F"]]] nil]
```

Is it right?

Comment: I have tried `(vector-zip ["A" ["B" "C" "D"["E" "F"]] ])`. It returns `[["A" ["B" "C" "D" ["E" "F"]]] nil]`. Is it right? Could you explain briefly? @cfrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's right. Some tests of your code:

```
(require '[clojure.zip :as zip])

(def zv (zip/vector-zip ["A" ["B" "C" "D"["E" "F"]]]))

(-> zv zip/next) ; => ["A" {:l [], :pnodes [["A" ["B" "C" "D" ["E" "F"]]]], :ppath nil, :r (["B" "C" "D" ["E" "F"]])}]

(-> zv zip/next zip/node) ; => "A"

(-> zv zip/next zip/next zip/next zip/node) ; => "B"

(-> zv zip/next zip/next zip/children) ; => ("B" "C" "D" ["E" "F"])
```